# VueJS: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foo')"

Tags: vue.js

My v-for loop looks like this:

```
<ul v-if="item.categorie_string">
    <li v-for="(cat_int,index) in item.categorie_string.split(',')" :key="index">
        {{myarray[cat_int].categoryname}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Variable *`categorie_string`* can be a string like `='1,2,3'`, `='5'` or `= NULL`

To prevent the error where `categorie_string == null` I added *`v-if="item.categorie_string"`* to the parent element `<ul>` but I still get:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categoryname')"
```

Shouldn't this be working?
It works fine if I test it with an integer instead of `cat_int`.

Comment: How does your "myarray" look like, also is it populated?

Comment: If myarray has three elements, then categorie_string should be "0,1,2" and "1,2,3" will give undefined on the last iteration.

Comment: Good point @Dejan.S, yes 'myarray' is populated by default. The issue was really just cat_int being empty. I could solve it with Laurens solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also check if `myarray[cat_int]` exists:

```
<ul v-if="item.categorie_string">
    <li v-for="(cat_int,index) in item.categorie_string.split(',')" :key="index">
        <span v-if="myarray[cat_int]">{{myarray[cat_int].categoryname}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You don't need a span just for a v-if, you can use `<template v-if=""></template>`